# Is there a maximum number of request you can put into one request message set using QBFC?

Tags: c#, intuit-partner-platform, qbfc

I tried to use [QBFC v13](https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0250_qb/0020_get_set_up/sdk_downloads) to construct a request message set that contains 46 customers pending to be created in [QuickBooks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QuickBooks).

The program throws **`string too long`** exception.

I'm wondering if there a maximum number of request you can put into one request message set.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Theoretically, no. The real limit you run into is when you run out of memory.

With that said, this error:

```
string too long
```

Doesn't sounds like an out of memory or too many requests type error. It sounds like you have a string that's too long in part of your qbXML request (the maximum field lengths are documented in the QuickBooks OSR).

Are you sure you don't have a string that's too long in part of your request? Did you check?

Answer (score 0):

you error isnt related to the number of requests your sending. I will say though there is a limit to the number of requests you can send in one message set. I cant seem to get a definite number out of anyone though. I tried importing 20,000 line items worth of credit memos each with about 10-15 line items per credit memo and about 2 extra requests per credit memo for custom fields setting and clearing and this errored out every time. When I cut back my data to about 15,000 line items everything went through no problem.